# How to create a matrix of the sums of nearby numbers in a matrix in python without use of numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, matrix

I have a x by x matrix like below

```
matrix=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

And a range

```
range_of_addition=1
```

I would then create a new matrix which sums all numbers within the range of an element in the matrix.

```
new_matrix=[[12,21,16],[27,45,33],[24,39,28]]
```

The first element is 12 because it is 1+2+4+5. Likewise the center element is the sum of all elements in the original matrix because all elements are in range.

How do I create a matrix of the same size as the original matrix but each element is the sum of itself and all elements within the specified range of itself?

Comment: Please provide your expected output matrix

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What don't you understand about creating a matrix?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut I've updated it

Comment: @PeterWood I would like to create an output like the one now updated

Comment: How do you obtain `21` ?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut 1+2+3+4+5+6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using numpy (I think it's a bit less flexible than using numpy however, I don't know numpy enough to give a proper opinion):

```
def matrix_get(matrix, position, offset):
    if position[0]+offset[0] < 0 or position[1]+offset[1] < 0:
        return 0
    # I'm using try/except to catch out of range error; in which case, this will return 0
    try:
        return matrix[position[0]+offset[0]][position[1]+offset[1]]
    except:
        return 0

new_matrix = []
row = []
total = 0

for r, a in enumerate(matrix):
    for c in range(len(a)):
        for x in range(-1, 2):
            for y in range(-1, 2):
                total += matrix_get(matrix, (r, c), (y, x))
        row.append(total)
        total = 0
    new_matrix.append(row)
    row = []

print(new_matrix)
# [[12, 21, 16], [27, 45, 33], [24, 39, 28]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is convolutional task.
Input:

```
a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
              [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
              [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
              [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
              [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

conv_filter = np.array([[1,1,1],
                        [1,1,1],
                        [1,1,1]])
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np

def conv2d(a, f):
    b = np.zeros([a.shape[0]+int(f.shape[0]/2)*2,a.shape[1]+int(f.shape[0]/2)*2])
    for i in range(1,b.shape[0]-int(f.shape[0]/2)):
        for j in range(1,b.shape[1]-int(f.shape[0]/2)):
            b[i][j] = a[i-1][j-1]
    s = f.shape + tuple(np.subtract(b.shape, f.shape) + 1)
    strd = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    subM = strd(b, shape = s, strides = b.strides * 2)
    return np.einsum('ij,ijkl->kl', f, subM)

conv2d(a,conv_filter)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 12.,  21.,  27.,  33.,  24.],
       [ 33.,  54.,  63.,  72.,  51.],
       [ 63.,  99., 108., 117.,  81.],
       [ 93., 144., 153., 162., 111.],
       [ 72., 111., 117., 123.,  84.]])
```